# Choosing Between Different RewriteRules for HTTPS Redirection in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server

I'm trying to configure my .htaccess file for HTTPS redirection, but I'm unsure which rule is more suitable for my case. Here are the two RewriteRules I'm considering:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [some_params]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [some_params]
```

The first rule uses server variables to redirect to the same requested URL with HTTPS, while the second redirects every request to "https://example.com/" with the requested path appended.

I'm unsure of the implications and potential issues with each approach. Could someone explain the differences between these two RewriteRules and suggest which might be more suitable for a single domain vs. multiple domains? Thank you."

In my knowledge,  If we have multiple domains pointing to the same .htaccess file, this rule will work correctly for all of them because it doesn't hardcode the domain name. Is there anything else, I am missing

Comment: "this rule will work correctly for all of them" - It depends what you are trying to do... Why do you have multiple domains pointing to the same host? Do you want to canonicalise the requested hostname or not? What about www vs non-www? Are you implementing HSTS? The first rule is unnecessarily capturing the URL-path - but maybe this is required by the preceding _conditions_ (which you've not included)?

Answer (score 0):

> In my knowledge, If we have multiple domains pointing to the same .htaccess file, this rule will work correctly for all of them because it doesn't hardcode the domain name.

Yes, that's correct.  The first rule takes into account the hostname (from the HTTP request), as well as the full request URI.  That's what I would use.

I also suggest using normal config files for this rather than `.htaccess` files, which have to be loaded, parsed, and applied for every request.

Comment: Which one do you think is more better one

Comment: @MuhammadTahirQaiser I would use the first one.

Comment: I would also go with the first rule, but it can be simplified: `RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]`. Since you do not use whatever is captured by the matching pattern you do not have to capture anything in the first place.